# Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Web has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, clr, vwdexpress

I created a new MVC 4.5 c# project like any other project.. And i can run the site, debug the site, browse the site all i want. click on the same link 20 times with no error, and i can press f5 to refresh the page, **but only once??!!**

When i click f5 the seccond time i get this following error:

Error details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: vwdexpress.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 11.0.50522.1
  Problem Signature 03: 4fbaf6fb
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17626
  Problem Signature 06: 4f9f0f5d
  Problem Signature 07: 4631
  Problem Signature 08: 5e2
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.PathTooLongException
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1030
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the RTM version?

Comment: @JonSkeet I... No... Downloading now!

Comment: @JonSkeet That totally did it! Thanks :D